# Почему в React (в методе map) не получается использовать item в цепочке вызова свойств объекта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне нужно было отрендерить большое количество одинаковых элементов (карточек), которые должны были отличаться картинкой и названием. Вот компонент для создания экземпляра карточки:

```
  function PokemonCard(props) {

  return (
    <figure className="PokemonCard">
      <img
        src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/${props.pokemonKey}.png`}
        alt={props.pokemonName}
      />
      <figcaption>
        {props.pokemonName}
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  )
};
```

Вот как я рендерил их в App компоненте:

```
function App() {
  const arr = Array.from(Array(50).keys());
  const pokemons = useSelector((state) => state.pokemonsList.pokemons);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPokemonsList());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="cardsWrapper"
      >
        {pokemons.results
        && arr.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <PokemonCard
              key={item}
              pokemonKey={++item}
              pokemonName={pokemons.results[item].name}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Здесь важно `const arr = Array.from(Array(50).keys());`. Я создал массив заполненный числами от 0 до 49, который я потом использую, чтобы запустить map (в случае успешного запроса данных) и вернуть нужное количество карточек с нужными мне свойствами.

После успешного запроса, в store сидят вот такие данные:

```
pokemons: {
  count: 1050,
  next: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=50&limit=50",
  previous: null,
  results: [
    {
      "name": "bulbasaur",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
    },
    {
      "name": "ivysaur",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
    },
...
```

В этом виде, из-за строчки `pokemonName={pokemons.results[item].name}` react выдаёт ошибку **"TypeError: pokemons.results[item] is undefined"**. Но если объявить новую переменную и присвоить ей `item`, то всё будет работать, т.е.:

```
      {pokemons.results
        && arr.map((item, index) => {

          let sameItem = item; //добавляем эту строчку

          return (
            <PokemonCard
              key={item}
              pokemonKey={++item}
              pokemonName={pokemons.results[sameItem].name} //меняем item на sameItem 
            />
          )
        })}
```

Если использовать index вместо item, тоже будет всё работать.

```
{pokemons.results
&& arr.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <PokemonCard
      key={item}
      pokemonKey={++item}
      pokemonName={pokemons.results[index].name} //Ставим index вместо item
    />
  )
})}
```

**Вопрос.**
Почему переменная `item`, из которой в возвращаемый экземпляр карточки попадает обычное число (так же, как если бы мы использовали индекс), выдаёт undefined в цепочке вызова свойств объекта: `pokemons.results[item].name`? Хотя, если убрать `name`, то react вернёт такую ошибку: **"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, url})."** То есть, мы получаем нужный объект из масива, но не можем обратиться к его свойству дальше по цепочке. Почему здесь именно `item` в `map` создаёт такую проблему?
Следует добавить, что цепочка работает, если не писать её именно в свойстве экземпляра компонента (т.е. в `pokemonName`). Вот так тоже всё работает:

```
    {pokemons.results
    && arr.map((item, inbdex) => {
         
      let name = pokemons.results[item].name; //переносим цепочку в переменную     

      return (
        <PokemonCard
          key={item}
          pokemonKey={++item}
          pokemonName={name} //добавляем её сюда
        />
      )
    })}
```

Comment: так зачем нам массив `arr`  если как я понял мы все равно берем данные через `api` если мы можем просто сделать `fetch` и вывести столько элементов, сколько нам нужно

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Вы имеете ввиду, что можно было перебирать массив с данными конкретной длины, который мы получили: да, так и следовало бы поступить, но вопрос не в этом. Я сделал через самодельный костыль, и наткнулся на странную ошибку, природу которой не могу понять. Почему цепочка к конкретному свойству, которое мы пробрасываем в пропс экземпляра компонента, именно через переменную item, не работает?